# Google Chart without Google Spreadsheet

Tags: php, sql, google-visualization, google-sheets

I have a few questions regarding Google Chart Tools.

1. Do we actually need a spreadsheet to populate the charts?
2. Are we allowed to query a SQL Database and use the results as the data for the chart? If yes, in what format should it be?

This will be my first time using Google Chart Tools so I am confused about how things must be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use json as data source, so if you want, you could make a page that returns the query result in json format. Its all in the doc

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source.html

and there's a good exemple in the code playground:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#chartwrapper_with_remote_data

Good Luck